# Vimeo API Upload Stops Midway then TimeOut No Errors

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

To be clear, it's already working a few weeks ago, nothing has changed in the code. It was just lately that this issue started happening.

It happens at step 2 in the [upload instructions.](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-upload)

This is where I'm hitting the upload_link_secure. My headers are:

```
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 3878343
```

The request path looks like this: `PUT https://1512435602.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=122011931&video_file_id=891441285&signature=cd07292b334345b32b5df12fef492e86&v6=1 http/1.1`

and the binary 3878343-byte body.

And the video does not appear on Vimeo.

However, when I tried to upload the videos normally using the vimeo website, it works.

There is no specific percentage where it stops, it seems random. And then sometime later `Connection timed out`.

There's no other error indicating what caused the issue.

Please help.
Thanks,

Comment: please help me vimeo peeps

Comment: Does it timeout consistently? Do you attempt to resume the upload (per step 3 in the upload instructions https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-upload)?

Comment: hi sorry for the very late reply, the project was paused so I moved to a different project. Anyway, yes I failed to implement the **verification** if completed part, then **patching** if not. Once I did that, it worked. It seems that the TimeOut happens when internet connection slows or spikes midway, and should be resumed after. Please post it as an answer together w/ the explanation so that I can accept. Thank you! :)